# Ruby Regex: negative lookahead with unlimited matching before

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to be able to match a phrase like:

```
I request a single car
// or
I request a single person
// or
I request a single coconut tree
```

but not

```
I request a single car by id
// nor
I request a single person by id with friends
// nor
I request a single coconut tree by id with coconuts
```

Something like this works:

```
/^I request a single person(?!\s+by id.*)/
```

for strings like this:

```
I request a single person
I request a single person with friends
```

But when I replace the person with a matcher (.*) or add the $ to the end, it stops working:

```
/^I request a single (.*)(?!\s+by id.*)$/
```

How can I accomplish this but still match in the first match *everything* before the negative lookahead?

Comment: This is really not a job for a regex in my opinion. Why not match all strings `I request a ` and then remove all stings that match `by id`  ? Very simple logic that will be much easier to understand that a complicated regex.

Comment: Because this is for Cucumber matches.

Comment: Also, it may take a minute to figure out, but that doesn't mean the solution won't be simple.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I just got it.  Right after asking the question.  Instead of a creating lookahead *after* the thing I want to capture, I create a lookahead *before* the thing I want to capture, like so:

```
/^I request a single (?!.*by id.*)(.*[^\s])?\s*$/
```

Comment: `\s*$` doesn't do anything. :-)

Comment: I beg your pardon.  It's fine now.  You can replace `[^\s]` with `\S`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `)` to match `(` in `(.*\)`. Perhaps that's a typo, since you tested. After fixing that, however, there's still a problem:

```
"I request a single car by idea" =~ /^I request a single (?!.*by id.*)(.*)$/
  #=> nil
```

Presumably, that should be a match. If you only want to know if there's a match, you can use:

```
r = /^I request a single (?!.+?by id\b)/
```

Then:

```
"I request a single car by idea" =~ r               #=> 0 
"I request a single person by id with friends" =~ r #=> nil
```

`\b` matches a word break, which includes the case where the previous character is the last one in the string. Notice that if you are just checking for a match, there's no need to include anything beyond the negative lookahead.

If you want to return whatever follows `"single "` when there's a match, use:

```
r = /^I request a single (?!.+?by id\b)(.*)/

"I request a single coconut tree"[r,1]              #=> "coconut tree"
"I request a single person by id with friends"[r,1] #=> nil
```